# The page is adding extra padding to the right of the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code. I'm trying to set the `class= Timeline` where it's shown in this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC2tP.png). but when I'm trying to do this the webpage adding an extra padding to the page. the padding is decrease and increase with margin-left of this CSS code:

```
   .Timeline{
  background-color: #EDEFF0;
  border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -130px;
  margin-left: 360px; 
  margin-right: 14px;
}
```

is anyone have any advise to do this work in different way?

Or anyone know how to solve this problem?

- Please I don't want to do it by remove the scroll bar by this code `overflow:hidden`

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- Set the page width to the size of device and set the zoom level to 1-->

    <!--<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet">-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" style="border-radius:0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <div class="container-flued">

        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">SUH</a>

            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" style="background-image: url('12-3-2016 5-51-30 PM.jpg');">
                </div>

            </form> 


        <div class="collegeLogo">
            <img src="https://sites.google.com/a/su.edu.krd/ahmed-alemdar/_/rsrc/1466038685850/home/unnamed.png" width="50px" height="50px" 
                 style="position: absolute; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; left: 0; right: 0;">
        </div>


        <div class="navbar-header navbar-right" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 6px;">    
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="listDesign">
            <li>
                <div class="dropdown" >
                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>
                    </button>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                        <li><a href="#">Join class</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Create class</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li> <img src="https://scontent-fra3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/11012973_971156699562295_5438409568173214004_n.jpg?oh=a165d22821b9a46f59fb95fa4f65d21f&oe=58AE701F" width="34px" height="34px" style="border: 2px; border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px; border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;"> 
            </li>

            <li style="margin-left: 0px;">
                <div class="dropdown" >
                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" style="border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;">
                        Siver Louis
                    </button>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                        <li style="text-align: center;"> Member name </li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>

                        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>

                        <li><a href="#">Classes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>

                        <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span>
                </button>
             </li>

        </ul>

        </div>

    </div>
</nav>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-3" style="">
        <div class="profile">

            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-K_p8F3QRyQ8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADo/w90iWVvnEPw/photo.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-profile">
            </div>

            <div class="member-name">
                <h2>Shareef Maulod Shareef</h2>
            </div>

            <hr/>

            <div class="info">
                <h3>Scientific Title: <span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal">Senior Lecturer </span></h3>
                <h3>Email: <span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal">shareef.shareef@su.edu.krd </span></h3>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-9" style="">
        <div class="cover">
            <img src="http://files.wallpapersfine.com/cool/ko_tapu_james_bond_island.jpg" class="img-cover">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>



<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1" style="background-color: white; height: auto; margin-top: 10px;">
        <div class="postOptions">
            <div class="list-group"><!--active  mazdla batr list-group-item active -->
                  <li><a href="#" class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"></span>Announcement</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>Assignment</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>Question</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"><!-- glyphicon glyphicon-repeat --></span>Reuse post</a></li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="streamHead" >
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs faq-cat-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#faq-cat-1" data-toggle="tab"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>Stream</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#faq-cat-2" data-toggle="tab"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Class members</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#faq-cat-2" data-toggle="tab"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-delete"></i>About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="Timeline">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="welcome" >
            <h2>Welcome to your class stream</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    #listDesign li{
    margin-left: 10px;
}

body{
  /*font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #EDEFF0;*/
}

.profile, .cover{
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.img-profile:hover, .img-cover:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image, .member-name{
  text-align: center;
}

.img-profile{
  border-radius: 50%;
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

hr{
  border-radius:3px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.member-name h2{
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.info h3{
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 286px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
}

 .img-cover{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
 }

.postOptions li{
  list-style: none;
}

.postOptions .list-group-item{
  text-align: center;
}

.postOptions span{
  float: left;
}


/*Timeline*/
.Timeline{
  background-color: #EDEFF0;
  border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -130px;
  margin-left: 360px; 
  margin-right: 14px;
}

.welcome h2{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: you want the "timeline" to be the same width as the picture? If that, the class container by default has padding: 15px;

Comment: The bootstrap styles contain many classes with a right margin of -15px; those are what cause the content to be wider than the body. I think you're not using them in the recommended way.

Comment: @Denisx yes I need that width. then how can I fix that extra padding? I'd try to add `padding-right: -15` to class `container` but it doesn't work?!

Comment: @MrLister , So what will be the way that will remove these margin-s and make the page fit to body?

Comment: .container { padding: 0; } should do the trick.

Comment: @Sivar I'm not sure what the proper way is accoirdinmg to bootstrap, but if you add `.row, .navbar-form, .navbar-nav {margin-left:0; margin-right:0}` at the end of your stylesheet, at least you'll be rid of the scrollbar. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/n70zy01u/1/) that behaves as your code does and [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/n70zy01u/) with the added css that has the scrollbar taken care of.

Comment: @Denisx this will remove the padding of the container, so will not affect the extra scroll!

Comment: @MrLister Okay Mr. I'm waiting. Thank you. :)

Comment: Bootstrap sets the width of `.container` elements to 750px when the window has a min-width of 768px. And your `.container` element has a left margin of 360px, giving it a total horizontal extent of 1110px. So to prevent this from happening, you have the following options; a) don't use Bootstrap; b) remove `class="container"` (since you're not using the class in the intended way anyway); or c) reverse what Bootstrap does by adding `@media (min-width: 768px) {.container {width:auto}}` to your own css. See [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/n70zy01u/2/).

Comment: Thank you @MrLister it helps me.